# Pandas Data Frame conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data Frame that Contains

```
employee_country          employee_branch      employee_email     employee_DOB       employee_mobile         position      salary
x                              a                  null             10/8/92               null                  normal        25000
y                              b                  aaa@aa.com        null               7896458978              experienced    50000
```

The code below will give two result set

```
a ={'emploee_email':['count'],'employee_mobile_number':['count'],'employee_DOB':['count']}
t = data_df.groupby(['employee_country','employee_branch','position']).position.count().unstack('position').fillna(0)
m = data_df.groupby(['employee_country','employee_branch']).agg(a)
```

print m will give

```
employee_country     employee_branch  count_employee_email    count_employee_dob    count_employee_mobile
   x                      a                0                        1                           0
```

print t will give

```
employee_country       employee_branch    count_experienced_employee   count_normal_employee   
     x                     a                     0                      1
```

i would like to get the result in the form of joining these two result set in the form like

```
employee_country   employee_branch    count_employee_email   count_employee_dob   count_normal_employee   count_experienced_employee
     x                    a                 0                          1                       1                        0
```

null value is not countable

Comment: You need more than the country and branch in order to merge.  You need a unique identifier for each employee which is not in your list of fields above.  Multiple employees could be working at the same branch in the same country, and there would be no way to distinguish one from the other. `employee_email` could work except for the null values.

Comment: @Teja K  it is not possible to merge using the line as you mentioned above